# close all browser tabs except current tab via javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to close all active tab except the current tab. Is this possible?

In my web site, when a user uses many tabs in same browser it fails. I want to close all tabs except the current one when any events triggered.

Here is a solution that I found:

```
function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
      close();
    }
}
```

This will work but how can I access other tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly control other tabs. You could instead pass them information by writing to cookies or local storage and having all tabs monitor that space.

However, I think that if your site doesn't work when open in multiple tabs, you should be focusing on fixing that problem.

Comment: on fixing problem i must change some things this make too much time